# Publisher sleep forever using roslaunch

Tags: ros, roslaunch, sleep

[image: Rosanswers logo]

When I ran a simple publisher in the tutorial (http://wiki.ros.org/ROS/Tutorials/WritingPublisherSubscriber%28c%2B%2B%29). I got a problem that if I ran it through launch file, the node will sleep forever. But if I ran it through rosrun [packagename] talker, it works fine. My launch file looks like this, can anyone help me?

```
<master auto="start"/>

<param name="use_sim_time" value="true"/>

<node pkg="hybridAstar" type="talker" name="talker" output="screen"/>
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/193905/publisher-sleep-forever-using-roslaunch/) by [Min](https://answers.ros.org/users/20355/min/) on ROS Answers with karma: 3 on 2014-09-30

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The problem is

```
<param name="use_sim_time" value="true"/>
```

This means the uses simulation time published to /clock topic by e. g. Gazebo or a rosbag started by `rosbag play --clock file.bag`.

See this
http://wiki.ros.org/Clock
ans this
http://answers.ros.org/question/193820/time-stamp-ros_info/?comment=193890#comment-193890
for info about clock and simulation time

This means your node will not spin before any other node (gazebo/rosbag) is started and publishes to /clock topic

---

Originally posted by [Wolf](https://answers.ros.org/users/4478/wolf/) with karma: 7555 on 2014-10-01

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Min](https://answers.ros.org/users/20355/min/) on 2014-10-01**:
Yes, problem solved. Thanks a lot ;)

**Comment by [Wolf](https://answers.ros.org/users/4478/wolf/) on 2014-10-01**:
Plz accept answer and close thread if issue is solved...